# Navigating a website and uploading a PDF using a submit button using JAVA

Tags: java, file, pdf, upload, web

To explain my situation, I currently have a large amount of PDFs (In the hundreds). Each PDF has a name associated with it and I need browse an external website my job uses to manage their files manually, clicking a button to "attach file" every time and manually selecting the file to upload to the site. If this sounds incredibly inefficient that's because it is, and doing this takes hours to finish while more of them pile up.

I already know how to deal with files, moving them around on a computer, and modifying them using JAVA, but I haven't done anything related to interacting with websites so I wouldn't know where to start.

I'll need to be able to perform the following actions or actions similar in order to complete what I have in mind.

- General browsing of a website
- Navigating through the website using
  links provided by buttons on the page
- Being able to click buttons.
- Reading Strings present on the screen in order to compare names *(Under a certain section there is a list of peoples names. If I detect that there are multiple people with the same name I want to skip the file and deal with it manually)*
- Clicking a button which brings up an upload menu and selecting a file to upload to it, or any other way of interacting with a feature such as this. *(Like when you click Computer on IMGUR and it asks you to choose an image you would like to upload)*

I'm not asking for anyone to straight up give me the answer I'm looking for *(Though I'm not opposed if you are aware of how to do things such as these and would like to share.)* but any guidance on where to find information on performing such actions would be helpful. I've already been searching and will be continuing to search for relevant information.

Thank you for any help you may be able to give.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want to automate some manual steps on a browser. You can take a look at [Selenium WebDriver](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/webdriver/).